# Why does the tag "css3-transitions" exist as "Watched Tags" if it does not exist on this site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-watching

I saw this tag in the section of "**Watched Tags**" like you can see in the screenshot and my question is:

This is a tag from Stack Overflow "in watched tags" or is it because I don't have access to this tags for my reputation?

I would like comment only about this and report this error (I think that is an error).

[image]

I got this error:

[image]

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312208/289905). Try the tag’s synonym target, [tag:css-transitions], instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That "(s)" means it's a synonym, not an actual tag.

If you want to follow that tag, you need to follow the master tag, [css-transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transitions). You can see the synonyms for that tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-transitions/synonyms).

Comment: In this case trying to select an (s) entry on that list should automatically select the master tag rather than failing and giving you an error message that doesn't include what the master tag is.

Comment: @TylerH I agree that it should have a better error message. The rest of the behavior could cause some confusion depending on the tag - not all synonyms are obvious to some users, so it would make sense to tell you "if you'd like to follow this tag, follow [master tag] instead"... with no notice about the fact it's a synonym, one might not know how they added "performance" when they chose to follow [one of these instead](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/performance/synonyms), for example.

Answer (score 3):

Starting earlier today, tag synonyms now remap to their targets on submit, matching the behaviour of the Ask Question page.